# Select All with react-hook-form multiple checkbox not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have requirement to create filters by dynamic data with multiple checkboxes and each group having select/unselectall option. I am able to create structure with react-hook-form and mock data but select/unselect all case is not working for me. I am New to React Js and react-hook-form. Please Help.

For my requirement, I created a POC and able to create structure with checkboxes in react-hook-form. But not able to handle select/unselect all case, as it is to be separate dynamic for each group.
[image: Requirement structure]

Mock Data - [image: Mock Data]

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import filterData from "./app/myData";
function MyDropdown() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors, getValues, setValue} = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      divison: ["NC"],
      group: ["AF"],
    },
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {Object.keys(filterData).map((ele) => (
          <div>
            <div>{filterData[ele].name}</div>
            <br></br>
            <div>
              <label>
                Select All
                <input type="checkbox" value="all" {...register(`selectAll${filterData[ele].name}`)}></input>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              { filterData[ele] &&
                filterData[ele].options &&
                filterData[ele].options.map((ele1) => (
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        {...register(filterData[ele].id)}
                        type="checkbox"
                        value={ele1.key}
                      />{" "}
                      {ele1.value} {ele1.key}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <br></br>
          </div>
        ))}
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyDropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this code I found on Git forum for react-hook-form.
https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/8563
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-antonelli-qcu3j3?file=/src/App.js:399-407

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const vegetables = ["carrot", "tomato", "potato", "onion"];

export default function App() {
  const { control, watch, setValue, register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (watch("all")) {
      vegetables.forEach((veges) => setValue(veges, true));
    } else {
      vegetables.forEach((veges) => setValue(veges, false));
    }
  }, [watch().all]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (watch(Object.keys(watch()).slice(1)).every((veges) => veges)) {
      setValue("all", true);
    }
    if (watch(Object.keys(watch()).slice(1)).some((veges) => !veges)) {
      setValue("all", false);
    }
  }, [...Object.keys(watch()).slice(1)]);

  console.log(watch());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Vegetables</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input type="checkbox" {...register("all")} />
        <span>All Vegetables</span>

        <div
          style={{
            padding: "10px",
            border: "1px solid blue",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column"
          }}
        >
          {vegetables.map((veges) => (
            <div key={veges}>
              <input type="checkbox" {...register(veges)} name={veges} />
              <span>{veges}</span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```